# Forked child keeps being terminated with status 0x008B

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork

I'm on a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.10 installed on, and I'm new using it. My code creates 100 forked child that works on a shared memory. SOMETIME I get this message

Sender(Pid = (childPID)) terminated with status 0x008B.

Searching in the web I found that could be a SIGSEGV error. Is it true?
Finally, is there any way to find WHERE the code fails in over 1000 lines? I tryed using this Guide: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html to find the error with gdb but my terminal says me that I have "No Stack". I'm totally new with this kind of problems, any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have "no stack", it could hint towards you having a buffer overflow on *stack* which would have overwritten the saved stack pointer on return.

Comment: Recompile your program with debugging symbols. Add `-g3` or `-ggdb3` to gcc.

Answer (score 0):

> Sender(Pid = (childPID)) terminated with status 0x008B.
>
> Searching in the web I found that could be a SIGSEGV error. Is it true?

Yes, that indicates termination by signal 11 (0xB).

> Finally, is there any way to find WHERE the code fails in over 1000 lines?

I'd run the program with `valgrind`.